# Pandas: Create a new column returning True or False if all the other values in the row are empty strings

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a new column in my pandas dataframe that will have a value of True if all  values in the other columns are empty strings (blank strings with length greater than zero also count! e.g. `'       '`) or False if at least one value is not an empty string.

```
>>> d
{'col1': ['', '2'], 'col2': ['', 'alpha']}
>>> df =pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I would like something like this

```
col1       col2       new_column

""          ""          True

"2"       "alpha"       False
```

Comment: `df['new_col'] = ~df.any(1)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['      ', '2'], 'col2': ['', 'alpha']})
df['new_col'] = df.replace(' ', '').any(axis=1)
```

Your dataframe will become :

```py
    col1    col2    new_col
0               True
1   2   alpha   True
```

As you may encounter blank lines with length greater than zero, the `.replace(' ', '')` will make them have length zero

Comment: Was close!
df['new_col'] = df.applymap( lambda x:x.strip() ).any(axis=1) seems to have done the trick